# Add rows simultaneously in to different worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel

I have one worksheet (A) with many tables separated by 2 rows each table. I also have an other worksheet (B) whose data is linked to the data in the tables of worksheet A.

I need to add new data in each table in A, so I add new rows in each table but when that happens, B doesnt follow this new lines added in A.

I want to add new rows in A that automatically add in B getting the information automatically from A